# Add comment guidance has very low contrast text

Tags: feature-request, design, accessibility

This showed up the first time I added a comment:

[image: Comment newbie advice]

The black on dark blue is very hard to read. I think it should use the standard code colour of `code`. so it would look like:

> Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: `[link](http://example.com)` `_italic_` `**bold**`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: `@peter` or `@PeterSmith` will both work. [Learn more about formatting...](/#blank)

It does seem to pass WCAG AA, but not AAA - and it's even smaller than their sample.